# Nodejs - "Sending https request to the same domain multiple times" fail to get the SSL cert each time

Tags: node.js, http, ssl

I'm trying to grab the SSL details of URLs and it works when requesting for multiple unique hosts.

Yet, when requesting for the same host, for some reason, only the certificate for the 1st request returns but not others.

It feels like there is a cache/session that keeps the SSL handshake and doesn't perform.

Here is a code to replicate it:

```
var request       = require('request')

var r = request({
  url: 'https://google.com/',
  method: 'HEAD',
  gzip: true,
  followRedirect: false,
    followAllRedirects: false
});

r.on('response', function(res) {
  certDetails = (res.req.connection.getPeerCertificate())
  console.log('*********1st Request**********');
  console.log(certDetails);
})



setTimeout (function() {
  var r = request({
    url: 'https://google.com/',
    method: 'HEAD',
    gzip: true,
    followRedirect: false,
    followAllRedirects: false
  });

  r.on('response', function(res) {
    certDetails = (res.req.connection.getPeerCertificate()) // works
    console.log('*********2nd Request**********');
    console.log(certDetails);
  })
}, 5000)
```

The 2nd request is sent 5 seconds later to the same host and it fails to get the certificate details.

Yet, if we keep the 1st host as google.com and the 2nd one as yahoo.com, both are retrieved (as they are unique and possibly not cached).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the answer.

The requests can be sent with:

```
agent: new Agent({
   maxCachedSessions: 0
}),
```

so that they are not cached.